# How to optimize my javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have inherited a piece of code which has a series of functions like the following:

```
$("#data[User][notify_one_day_out]").change(function () {
    $("#updatenotificationsform").submit();
}

$("#data[User][notify_one_month_out]").change(function () {
    $("#updatenotificationsform").submit();
 }
```

and this goes on and on. How do I just write one function that does the same thing since every ID begins with data. Sorry am a JS newbie

Thanks

Comment: Isn't this just the exact same code twice? Als, `#data[User][notify_one_day_out]` matchs the element with ID `data` if the `User` and `notify_one_day_out` attributes are set. If they are part of the ID instead, you have to escape `[]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this would probably work for you:

```
$('[id^="data"]').change(function() {
 $("#updatenotificationsform").submit();
}
```

That basically says: grab all the elements with an Id starting with the string "data", you can read more about that here: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Let me know if that helps!

**Edit**

Alternatively if you can modify your mark up, you could assign the same class to all those elements, and then just select using the class selector.

Comment: The alternative solution you offer here is definitely the way to go if you have control over the html output.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Deleteman's sound advice, remember that you can specify multiple selectors for `$()`, e.g.:

```
$(  "#data[User][notify_one_month_out]",
    "#data[User][notify_one_day_out]",
    "#some-other-selector",
    // ...
).change(function () {
  $("#updatenotificationsform").submit();
}
```

Comment: You'd have to escape the `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually stack up those Jquery selectors would that be enough of a help or do you really have ALOT of them?

```
$("#data[User][notify_one_day_out], #data[User][notify_one_month_out]").change(function ()     
{
    $("#updatenotificationsform").submit();
}
```